# Why is my $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof incorrect?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

**Prove that $f(x)= \sqrt{4+x^2}$ is continuous at $x_0$ using the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition of continuity.**

**Textbook proof:**

$|\sqrt{4+x^2}-\sqrt{4+x^2}|=\frac{|4+x^2-(4+{x_0}^2)|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}+\sqrt{4+{x_0}^2}}=\frac{|x^2-{x_0}^2|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}+\sqrt{4+{x_0}^2}}=\underbrace{\frac{|x+x_0|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}+\sqrt{4+{x_0}^2}}}_{K(x,x_0)}|x-x_0|$

$K(x,x_0)=\frac{|x+x_0|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}+\sqrt{4+{x_0}^2}}\leq \frac{|x|+|x_0|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}+\sqrt{4+{x_0}^2}}=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}+\sqrt{4+{x_0}^2}}+\frac{|x_0|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}+\sqrt{4+{x_0}^2}}$

$\leq\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}+\frac{|x_0|}{\sqrt{4+{x_0}^2}}$

$\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}}\leq 1$ and $\frac{|x_0|}{\sqrt{4+{x_0}^2}}\leq 1\Rightarrow K(x,x_0)\leq 2\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|\leq2|x-x_0|<2\delta=\epsilon$

So, for all $\epsilon$ we can choose a $\delta$ such that $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

**My proof:**

$|\sqrt{4+x^2}-\sqrt{4+x^2}|=\frac{|4+x^2-(4+{x_0}^2)|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}+\sqrt{4+{x_0}^2}}=\frac{|x^2-{x_0}^2|}{\sqrt{4+x^2}+\sqrt{4+{x_0}^2}}\leq |x^2-{x_0}^2|$

$=|x-x_0||x-x_0+2x_0|<\delta^2+2|x_0|\delta$

Case $\delta<1$:

$\delta^2+2|x_0|\delta<\delta(1+2|x_0|)=\epsilon$

$\Rightarrow$ If $1+2|x_0|>\epsilon$ we have $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{1+2|x_0|}$

Case $\delta=1$:

$\Rightarrow$ If $1+2|x_0|\leq\epsilon$ we have $\delta = 1$

**Why do I get a different result for delta? What did I do wrong?**

Comment: It makes no sense in your proof to do a case analysis on whether $\delta<1$ or $\delta=1$ when you haven't yet decided what $\delta$ is going to be. Remember, it's _your choice_ what to use as $\delta$ as long as it works, and there will be many different possible values that all work.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I see, so there are many possible solutions. An other question: Given $\delta^2+2|x_0|\delta=\epsilon$, can I solve for $\delta$ using the quadratic formula?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: So $\delta_{1,2}= -|x_0|\pm\sqrt{{x_0}^2+\epsilon}$ or is this incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your proof, there is nothing wrong with it. Only that dealing with $\delta=1$ is not needed, as you can always request $\delta<1$.

As for why the "results" are different? There is no result. No one says that for a given $f$ and a given $x_0$ and a given $\varepsilon$, there is a single $\delta$. Any $\delta$ less than a given $\delta$ will work, so there is not obvious choice of a "best" $\delta$ or anything like that.

Comment: Why can I always request $\delta<1$? I thought I must choose a delta according to one particular epsilon. What if the given epsilon is $\epsilon\geq 1+2|x_0|$?

Comment: Given an $\varepsilon $, you have to produce a $\delta $. If you need it to be less than one, so be it, as long as it works. Your proof shows that you can always take $\delta $ to be the minimum between $1$ and $\varepsilon /(1+2|x_0|) $.

Comment: So, can I also request $\delta=1$? That would make things much easier. Or is it only restricted to $\delta<1$?

Comment: What you have to do is, when $\varepsilon>1+2|x_0|$, you take $\delta=1$. When $\varepsilon\leq1+2|x_0|$, you take $\delta=\varepsilon/(1+2|x_0|)$.

Comment: But you said I can always request $\delta <1$. Now you're saying when $\epsilon >1+2|x_0|$ I must take $\delta =1$. I'm sorry I but I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the things that matter, I provide an argument for your reference; it is more succinct:

Let $x_{0} \in \Bbb{R}$. If $x \in \Bbb{R}$, then
$$
|\sqrt{4+x^{2}} - \sqrt{4+x_{0}^{2}}| = \frac{|x-x_{0}||x+x_{0}|}{\sqrt{4+x^{2}} + \sqrt{4 + x_{0}^{2}}} < |x-x_{0}||x+x_{0}|;
$$
if in addition $|x-x_{0}| < 1$, then $|x| - |x_{0}| \leq |x-x_{0}| < 1$, implying $|x+x_{0}| \leq |x|+|x_{0}| < 1 + 2|x_{0}| =: M_{0}$, implying 
$|x-x_{0}||x+x_{0}| < |x-x_{0}|M_{0}$; given any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have 
$|x - x_{0}|M_{0} < \varepsilon$ if in addition $|x-x_{0}| < \varepsilon/M_{0}$. All in all, for every $x_{0} \in \Bbb{R}$ and every $\varepsilon > 0$, it holds that $|x-x_{0}| < \min \{ 1, \varepsilon/M_{0} \}$ implies $|f(x) - f(x_{0})| < \varepsilon$.